# regular expression to group matches and non-matches

Tags: python, regex

i have the following string. i want to tokenize this such that there are groups for both the matched curly braces and non match

```py
str='{field1}somestring{field2}somestring2{feild3}<somestring3>'
```

i know i can tokenize the curly braces with:

```py
re.findall('({[^}]*})', str) 
['{field1}', '{field2}', '{feild3}']
```

But what i really want is:

```py
['{field1}', 'somestring', '{field2}', 'somestring2', '{feild3}', '<somestring3>']
```

I am having trouble doing this...the closest i've come so far is the following

```py
re.findall('(.*?)({[^}]*})(.*?)', str) 
[('', '{field1}', ''), ('somestring', '{field2}', ''), ('somestring2', '{feild3}', '')]
```

But you can see it creates an array of three groups, with empty strings, and the last token `<somestring3>` is not getting tokenized.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use `re.split()` instead of `re.findall()`.

Comment: Or `re.findall(r'{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+', text)`

Comment: Barmar: that works nicely. though i do still get an empty first string. i can live with that.  @WiktorStribiżew perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tokenize a string into strings with `{...}` and those not containing `{` and `}` using

```py
re.findall(r'{[^{}]*}|[^{}]+', text)
```

*Details*:

- `{[^{}]*}` - a `{`, then zero or more chars other than `{` and `}`, and then a `}` char
- `|` - or
- `[^{}]+` - one or more chars other than `{` and `}`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FMHJMr/1).